# @Html.DropDownListFor Selected Item Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am looping and attempting to change the "Selected" item in a List on the fly.

But, the default item is not being selected. When I look at the source html there is no "selected" parameter.

Here is my class:

```
public List<SelectListItem> buyerDropdown { get; set; }
public int selectedBuyer { get; set; }
```

Here is my code:

```
@foreach (American_States state in Model.AmericanStates)
    {
        {
            // change the "selected" buyer to match the buyer Id for this state
            Model.buyerDropdown.Where(x => x.Value == Convert.ToString(state.Buyer.Id)).FirstOrDefault().Selected = true;
        }
        <tr>
            <td>@state.name</td>
            <td>@state.Title.OfficerName</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedBuyer, Model.buyerDropdown, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }
```

When I step into the code I can see the correct item in the SelectItemList being updated to "Selected".

I cannot see why the correct item in the dropdown is not being selected?

**UPDATE**

Based on T-Roy I now have this code:

When I debug the correct value is being calculated for the selected index value but the dropdown still doesn't select the default value:

```
@foreach (American_States state in Model.AmericanStates)
    {
        {
            // change the "selected" buyer to match the buyer Id for this state
            string selectedOption = Model.buyerDropdown.Single(x => x.Value == Convert.ToString(state.HudHomeStore_Buyer.Id)).Value;
        <tr>
            <td>@state.name</td>
            <td>@state.HudHomeStore_Title.OfficerName</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedBuyer, new SelectList(Model.buyerDropdown, "Value", "Text", selectedOption), new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does your model class handle selectedBuyer? it looks like you are using the same property for all AmericanStates?

Comment: You code simply makes no sense. You creating multiple dropdowns inside a loop that bind to the same property. You not only generating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes), but only the first dropdown will ever be bound to your model when you submit. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: And model binding works by binding to the value of your property so its the value of `selectedBuyer` that determines what is selected (if the value of `selectedBuyer` matches one of the option values, then it will be selected, but that makes no sense inside a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, when dealing with trying to find values based off of their `ID`'s.. it's best practice to use the `Single()` method because `ID`'s should be unique.  If you use `.Where` tagged up with `FirstOrDefault` it's implied that there could be more than 1 value with the same `ID`, whereas `Single` is responsible for finding the one and only unique record.

```
@foreach (American_States state in Model.AmericanStates)
{
    {
        int selectedOptionInt;
        // change the "selected" buyer to match the buyer Id for this state
        var selectedOption = Model.buyerDropdown.Single(x => x.Value == Convert.ToString(state.Buyer.Id)).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var isNumber = Int32.TryParse(selectedOption, selectedOptionInt);
    }
    <tr>
        <td>@state.name</td>
        <td>@state.Title.OfficerName</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedBuyer, new SelectList(Model.buyerDropdown, "Key", "Value", selectedOptionInt), new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: @TrevorDaniel Is `selectedOption` receiving the correct value?

Comment: the correct id is being calculated but the dropdown still refuses to make it the default value

Comment: @TrevorDaniel Can you update your question to show the changes you've made?

Comment: @TrevorDaniel see my update.  Try converting to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of foreach loop you may need to use simple for loop. This is because the name attribute for the generated dropdownlist will not be in a format expected by MVC. I think the naming requires indexer for proper binding. This will also help the POST issue which you may face potentially while using foreach.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AmericanStates.Count(); i++)
{
    {
        // change the "selected" buyer to match the buyer Id for this state
        var selectedOption = Model.buyerDropdown.Single(x => x.Value == Convert.ToString(state.Buyer.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    <tr>
        // Other controls
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AmericanStates[i].selectedBuyer, new SelectList(Model.buyerDropdown, "Key", "Value", selectedOption), new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
}
```